# C++ How to calculate the number time a string occurs in a data

Tags: c++, stdstring

I want to measure the following two things:

- How many times a comma appears in a
  std::std, e.g. if `str ="1,2,3,4,1,2,"`
  then `str.Count(',')` returns me `6` in case of above
  string
- The second thing is also similar to
  the first on but instead of single
  char i want to calculate the number
  of occurances of a string e.g
  `str.FindAllOccurancesOF("1,2,")`
  returns me `2`

Is there any builtin functions in c++ for calculating this or i need to write custom code for this?

Comment: The second one has several solutions, you will have to decide what an occurence actually is. What is the result of `str="AAAAAAAAAA"; str.FindAllOccurancesOf("AAA");`?

Comment: @Bo Persson Nice Catch But in our case the pattern must contains two or more elements in it e.g. "1,2," forms a pattern because it contain atleast two elements (i.e 1 and 2) but "1," doesn't form a pattern coz it contains only single element

Comment: I think what @Bo means is that you have to define the wanted behaviour for a case where you are counting occurrences of, say, `"AA"` in `"AAAAAAAA"`. Should the answer be 4 (no overlap) or 7 (with overlap)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using one of the std::string::find methods, you can step through the reference string, counting each time you find the sub-string. No need for copies or erases. Also, use `std::string::npos` to check whether the pattern has been found or not, instead of literal `-1`. Also, using the sub-string's size, `std::string::size()`, avoids hard coding the step size (literal `4` in other answers)

```
size_t stringCount(const std::string& referenceString,
                   const std::string& subString) {

  const size_t step = subString.size();

  size_t count(0);
  size_t pos(0) ;

  while( (pos=referenceString.find(subString, pos)) !=std::string::npos) {
    pos +=step;
    ++count ;
  }

  return count;

}
```

**EDIT**: This function does not allow for overlaps, i.e. searching for sub-string `"AA"` in string `"AAAAAAAA"` results in a count of `4`. To allow for overlap, this line

```
pos += step
```

should be replaced by

```
++pos
```

This will result in a count of `7`. The desired behaviour isn't properly specified in the question, so I chose one possibility.

Comment: You can't move forward by the size of the pattern, think of patterns of the form "aaaa" or "abcabc" etc.  - Not sure why this solution was chosen as correct.

Comment: @Rikardo, it passes my tests but maybe I missed something. Can you give me an example of string and sub-string for which it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm fairly new to CPP, can someone explain why pos = referenceString.find(subString, pos))? 

This is the only part of the code I'm confused about.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the first one -

```
std::string str="1,2,3,4,1,2," ;
std::count( str.begin(), str.end(), ',' ) ; // include algorithm header
```

**Edit :**

Using [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) -

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string str1 = "1,2,3,1,2,1,2,2,1,2," ;
        string str2 = "1,2," ;

        int count = 0 ;
        int pos = -4;

        while( (pos = str1.find(str2, pos+4) ) != -1 ) // +4 because for the next 
                                                       // iteration current found
                                                       // sequence should be eliminated
        {
            ++count ;         
        }
        cout << count ;
}
```

[IdeOne results](http://ideone.com/pw8nG)

Comment: Why are you erasing? why not just do a find from the current position +1 - your way is insanely inefficient.

Comment: @Rikardo - Thanks for improving my efficiency :)

Comment: you can't forward the position by the size of the pattern, you have to either build a prefix table kmp style or just find from the next position onward aka +1 from the current position.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `char*` (C-style) string then following can be tried (pseudo code):
For counting character occurred:

```
const char *str ="1,2,3,4,1,2,", *p = str - 1;
int count = 0
while(0 != (p = strchr(++p, ',')))
  count ++;
```

For counting string occurred:

```
const char *str ="1,2,3,4,1,2,", *p = str - 1;
int count = 0;
while(0 != (p = strstr(++p, "1,2,")))
  count ++;
```

Answer (score 1):

[string::find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) will start you on your way.