# How to know the number of appearances of a string inside an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Basically, I want to check how many times appears a string inside an array.

I'm doing online challenges and I came across this.

You first, input the number of how many elements the array has. Then you input some strings.

Example:

```
5
LOL
CODE
CODE
LOL
CODE
```

So, I have to **output the string** which has been typed most times. In this case that would be `CODE`.

How can I do that with C++?

Comment: I'm currently out of ideas.... I'm not a PROFESSIONAL coder. I'm currently at high school and I would like to expand my C++ knowledge for future college and therefore I'm doing online challenges and learning from eBooks only.

Comment: Anyway, that's not the answer of your question you wanted. Basically, I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to do. I looked up at hash tables, but didn't really get anything in my mind, so any kind of example or hint what to do is welcome to do!

Comment: You have to be more expressive, or express better. Do you want to know how many times a string appears inside a string? A function like this: `{A="hi word!"; Count('word',A);}` result: 1

Comment: You are correctly looking at hash maps.Keep looking, therein lies the solution. Google c++ stl maps.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067460/c-how-to-calculate-the-number-time-a-string-occurs-in-a-data

Comment: @Lucio: My question is, after you input all the strings in your array, you have to output the string which has been mentioned the most.

Comment: @user1929959 The functions from there also work for arrays?

Comment: most occurence element of array of STRINGS is what I have to find.. I'm still looking for help. :( hash tables too hard.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Why throwing yourself into challenges if you give up as soon as you are faced with a hard topic? Rather invest your time learning the hard topic, *then* do challenges.

Comment: In your question you are referring  the *array* as *string* and the *string* as *element*. Please edit your question clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about an approach with hash-maps or the like, but I whipped up a program which essentially is the brute force way of doing things. Basically you need to keep track of each string and how many types it appears using a dynamic array. Once you have gone through your input and analyzed each string and how many times it appears, you go through your dynamic array and see which string appears the most. Then you simply output it.

Try and do this yourself without the help of my program. If you cannot or if you get stuck just refer to the working program below which does what you ask:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//This struct represents a string and how many times it appears
struct strRefCount { //String and Reference Count
    unsigned int count;
    string str;
};

strRefCount strMode(string data) //String mode: returns the string which appears most often
{

    vector<strRefCount> allStrings; //Count of each time a string appears and what the string is
    string curString = ""; //The string we are currently reading (initialize to be empty)
    unsigned int strPos = 0; //The position (in the form of data[strPos]) which represents how far we have gotten in analyzing the string
    strRefCount *modeStringp; //Pointer to the string that appears most often

    while(data[strPos] != NULL) { //We will advance through data until we hit the null terminator in this loop
        curString.clear();
        while(data[strPos] != ' ' && data[strPos] != NULL) //Advance in the string until we hit a space or terminating null byte
        {
            curString += data[strPos]; //Append the string
            strPos++; //Advance one byte in data
        }

        bool flagStringFound = false; //This flag indicates that the string was already found before
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < allStrings.size(); i++)
        {
            if(allStrings[i].str == curString) //If this string is the same as the current entry
            {
                allStrings[i].count++;
                flagStringFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flagStringFound == false) //If the string is not present in allStrings, put it there and initialize it
        {
            strRefCount addElem; //Element to add to the end of the vector
            addElem.str = curString; //Last element's string is curString
            addElem.count = 1; //Last element's reference count is curString
            allStrings.push_back(addElem); //Add the element
        }

        //Make sure we don't repeat the loop if we are at the end of the string
        if(data[strPos] != NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //Now we have every string which appears in data and the number of times it appears
    //Go on to produce the correct output
    modeStringp = &(allStrings[0]); //Set modeStringp to the first string
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < allStrings.size(); i++) //Note that by setting i to 1 we skip the first element which is already in modeStringp
    {   
        if(allStrings[i].count > modeStringp->count) //If the current entry in allStrings is bigger than 
        {
            modeStringp = &(allStrings[i]); //Replace modeStringp with the current entry in allStrings
        }
    }

    return *modeStringp;
}

int main()
{
    string data;
    getline(cin, data); //Get the input (can't use cin as it doesn't allow for an entire line just space seperated string)

    strRefCount dataModeString = strMode(data); //Call out strMode function

    cout << endl << dataModeString.str << " appears most often with a total of " << dataModeString.count << " appearances.";

    getchar(); //This line is only here to make sure we don't quit before we see the output.

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This program](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5563017/) had worked for me.

The program create an array with the next records:

```
"Lucio", "John", "Lucio"
```

Then it sends that information to a function that returns the most referenced name. So it returns `Lucio`